# why get value item view in activity from fragment only in the last fragment is working

Tags: android, listview, spinner, grouping

i'm developing android apps. Sorry if my english is very bad. I have a problem, maybe friends here can help to solve my problem.

I'm creating a listview that can be grouped via layout and spinner tabs. 
[image]

In each fragment I create an inflate to one layout below :

**fragment_patient_ranap.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container_pasien_register"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue_50"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="4dp">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_pasien_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_view_border"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Cari Nama Pasien..."
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_pasien_register"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Progress Bar-->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_pasien_registrasi"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_two"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_pasien_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:divider="@color/blue_50"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/icons"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tidak Ada Data!"
        android:textColor="@color/accent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In layout *Main* i define TabLayout and Spinner like:

**activity_patient_ranap.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/holo_light"
tools:context="com.santosa.muhammadaa.mysantosa.PatientRanapActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_pasien_ranap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_title_label_pasien_ranap"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner_ruangan"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/title_pasien_ranap"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_ruangan"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_one"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/view_img_refresh"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/icons"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_img_refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_two"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_two"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/img_refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_autorenew_white_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="@color/icons"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primary"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/secondary_text" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

But when i get value Spinner from fragment just working in last fragment, in other fragments not working.

My code for every fragment TabLayout get value Spinner, example:

```
Spinner viewSpinner = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_ruangan);
```

Is there something wrong with my code flow?

Please help me... I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: Can you show me please how you show and hide your fragments?

Comment: i'am use adapter for add every fragment @MaximeClaude ... and when i get value item from activity in fragment. just working on last fragment.

Comment: What is not working? Is it that your are unable to select any value from any spinner except from the last one? Is it that only the last fragment's spinner isn't null (and has values?)

Comment: i don't know why is not working.. but yeah.. it is cannot select any value from any spinner except from the last fragment.. In the last fragment, get value from spinner working perfectly.. @MaximeClaude

Comment: Where do you define the item click listener of the spinner? Only in the last fragment or in the activity?

Comment: i define item click listener in every fragment.. like Spinner viewSpinner = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_ruangan). But the code just working in the last fragment. i confused for that.. @MaximeClaude

Comment: Because the last fragment is the one to be defined it is the only one working. You should define it once in the parent activity and find a way (example an event bus) to communicate between the fragments. This way, the spinner will be defined and alive during all the activity's life.

Comment: Can you give an example of how it should be with my case above ? @MaximeClaude

Answer (score 0):

Disclamer: This code was not tested, it is written to give you an idea of what I am talking about, you might need to change many lines because they might be broken. [This](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is event bus used here.

In the parent activity:

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 
    //other activity's views (example: searchView, Button etc)
    private Spinner viewSpinner;
    private Viewpager viewPager;
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener;
    private WeakReference<BaseActivity> activityWeakReference = null; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
     viewSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_ruangan);
     viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.your_viewpager);
     pageChangeListener = definePageChangeListener();
     viewPager.setAdapter(new YourPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
     viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener); //add a onPageChangeListener to the viewPager

     //logic to define your fragments
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
     if(pageChangeListener != null && viewPager != null)
         viewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener); //remove the onPageChangeListener from the viewPager
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
     super.onStop();
    }


    public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener definePageChangeListener(){
        return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //you have the selected fragment's position here, just pass it to the right fragment using event bus
                switch(position){
                    case 0: 
                        EventBus.getDefault.post(new PageSelectedEvent(Fragment1.class.getSimpleName()));
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        EventBus.getDefault.post(new PageSelectedEvent(Fragment2.class.getSimpleName()));
                        break;                  
                    case 2:                      
                        EventBus.getDefault.post(new PageSelectedEvent(Fragment3.class.getSimpleName()));
                        break;                   
                    case 3:                      
                        EventBus.getDefault.post(new PageSelectedEvent(Fragment4.class.getSimpleName()));
                        break;                   
                    default:                    
                        EventBus.getDefault.post(new PageSelectedEvent(Fragment1.class.getSimpleName()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        };
    }

    private class YourPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        ArrayList<CustomFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<CustomFragment>();
        public YourPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            //note that the fragments' constructor is up to you, you can have Fragment1(fragment.TAG, "id");
            fragments.add(new Fragment1()); //Fragment1 inherits CustomFragment that inherits Fragment class
            fragments.add(new Fragment2()); //Fragment2 inherits CustomFragment that inherits Fragment class
            fragments.add(new Fragment3()); //Fragment3 inherits CustomFragment that inherits Fragment class
            fragments.add(new Fragment4()); //Fragment4 inherits CustomFragment that inherits Fragment class
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }       
    }

    //this method will avoid memory leaks, yet it's result should always be checked to see if it is null
    public BaseActivity getActivityFromWeakReference(){
        activityWeakReference = activityWeakReference == null ?
                new WeakReference<BaseActivity>((BaseActivity)getActivity()) :
                activityWeakReference;
        return activityWeakReference.get();
    }

    public Spinner getViewSpinner(){
        if(viewSpinner == null)
            viewSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_ruangan);
        return viewSpinner;
    }
}
```

The event class:

```
public class PageSelectedEvent{
    private String fragmentName = "";

    public PageSelectedEvent(String fragmentName){
        if(fragmentName == null || fragmentName.isEmpty()) // remove this line and the following line at production
            throw new NullPointerException("The fragmentName is null or empty. I shouldn't be the case.");

        this.fragmentName = fragmentName;
    }

    public String getFragmentName(){
        return fragmentName;
    }
}
```

In `CustomFragment`:

```
//in CustomFragment (that will be inherited by each of the 4 fragments)
protected Spinner viewSpinner = null;

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

public void onPause(){
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(NothingEvent event) {
    //EventBus will throw an exception if there is no subscriber.
    //So NothingEvent will avoid that exception.
}

private class NothingEvent{}
```

Now in each of the fragments that inherit from `CustomFragment`, add this:

```
//now in each of the 4 fragments paste this code
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onPageSelectedEvent(PageSelectedEvent event) {
    if(event.getFragmentName().equals(this.getSimpleName())){
        ParentActivity parentActivityReference = ((ParentActivity)getActivity()).getActivityFromWeakReference();
        viewSpinner = parentActivityReference.getViewSpinner(); //here you are assigning the parent's spinner's reference so that the currently displayed fragment has a reference to the activity's
    }
}
```